# SVG Picture isn't displaying in the WidgetSpan on Flutter

Tags: flutter, svg, text, row, textspan

I've created a row that has RichText in, inside RichText I have TextSpan which has children of TextSpan and WidgetSpan.

Problem: When I do try and add WidgetSpan in between the TextSpan with an SVG Image, the website won't load. How can I get the SVG Image to display in between the TextSpans?

Flutter giver me this error when my website won't load and when I remove the WidgetSpan it goes away.

Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: '' Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///Users/ned/Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart:1694:12 –

```
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          RichText(
            text:TextSpan(
              children: <InlineSpan> [
                TextSpan(
                  text: 'Or continue with: ',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(85, 85, 85, 1),
                    fontSize: 13, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
                WidgetSpan(
                  child: SvgPicture.asset('images/google-icon.svg'),
                  alignment: PlaceholderAlignment.middle,
                ),
                TextSpan(
                  text: 'Google',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(3, 0, 137, 1),
                    fontSize: 13, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                  recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                    ..onTap = () { launch(
                        'https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/UrlLauncher-class.html'
                    );
                    },
                ),
```

Comment: *"the website won't load."* - what website? tried other widgets (just for test) like `Icon`, `Button` etc instead of `SvgPicture`?

Comment: A Flutter website I'm creating so I removed the WidgetSpan and it works but when I put it back in I get this Error in the Console:

Comment: Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: '<Unexpected Null Value>'

Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///Users/ned/Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart:1694:12

Comment: so what is in line `1694`, column `12`?

Comment: The box.dart file a with this code:

Comment: Size get size {
    assert(hasSize, 'RenderBox was not laid out: ${toString()}');
    assert(() {
      final Size _size = this._size;
      if (_size is _DebugSize) {
        assert(_size._owner == this);

Comment: SVG text elements can only have tspan, textPath as rendered children. Other rendered elements are invalid.

Comment: Thanks, is there any suggestion you could make to use the SVG without a WidgetSpan?

Comment: `child: Text.rich(
  TextSpan(
    children: [
      TextSpan(text: 'foo'),
      WidgetSpan(child: SvgPicture.string('<svg height="48" width="48"><path d="M0,0 L48,0 L48,48 Z"/></svg>')),
      TextSpan(text: 'bar'),
    ],
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 48),
  )
),` - does it work at you?

Comment: No it's still coming back with the same error: Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: file:///Users/ned/Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart:1694:12

Comment: ahh, i got it now, it does not work in flutter4web (`-d chrome`)

Comment: Thanks, I finally got it to work with using a web safe svg flutter package: instead: https://pub.dev/packages/websafe_svg#-readme-tab-

Comment: nice to know, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the package I used for the SVG. After changing to a websafe package: https://pub.dev/packages/websafe_svg and not using RichText, TextSpan, WidgetSpan Widgets it worked :)

```
        Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 13.0),
            child: new Text(
              "Or continue with: ",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Color.fromRGBO(85, 85, 85, 1),
                  fontSize: 13.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ),
          WebsafeSvg.asset('images/google_icon.svg',
        height: 13.0,
        width: 13.0,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
            child: GestureDetector(
              child: Text(
                "Google",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(3, 0, 137, 1),
                    fontSize: 13.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
                onTap: () => launch('https://google.com')
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```